# Sum of DATETIME in every section of a report

Tags: ms-access, datetime, reporting-services

I am having a report with multiple time differences. For example there are fields as below

> 3 days 4 hours 15 minutes
>
> 6 hours 12 minutes
>
> 1 hours 15 minutes

and there are many grouped sections... i want the sum of the time for each section independently.

Comment: Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` output

Comment: Of what relevance are the -sql tags?

Comment: What's the actual type in the database?  It appears to be character-based, which makes things difficult.  What type of accuracy do you need?  For instance, depending on time of year and location, days aren't always 24 hours.  Should values roll up to the next largest value (`12 hours + 12 hours = 1 day`)?  What's the smallest/largest unit?

Comment: Are you doing this in MySQL or ms-access?

Comment: You might get more help if you provide an SQL Fiddle or more details on your data structure. What are you trying to do? What have you already tried (include any relevant code)? What is your expected result compared to your actual result?

Comment: I'm sorry it wasn't clear... these values are on my Report. I need to sum up each section in the report in MS Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the above issue can be resolved by converting the time into seconds and adding them up.

There is a function to then convert the total number of Seconds into Days/hours/minutes and Seconds.

```
Function DHMS(Date1 As Date, Date2 As Date) As String
    Dim NumberOfSeconds As Long
    Dim NumberOfMinutes As Long
    Dim NumberOfHours As Long
    Dim NumberOfDays As Long

    'Number of seconds between the two dates
    NumberOfSeconds = Abs(DateDiff("s", Date1, Date2))

    'Calculate Days and remaining Seconds
    NumberOfDays = NumberOfSeconds \ 86400
    NumberOfSeconds = NumberOfSeconds Mod 86400

    'Calculate Hours and remaining Seconds
    NumberOfHours = NumberOfSeconds \ 3600
    NumberOfSeconds = NumberOfSeconds Mod 3600

    'Calculate Minutes and remaining Seconds
    NumberOfMinutes = NumberOfSeconds \ 60
    NumberOfSeconds = NumberOfSeconds Mod 60

    'Return the time remaining
    DHMS = NumberOfDays & " Day" & _
    IIf(NumberOfDays = 1, " ", "s ") & _
    NumberOfHours & " Hour" & _
    IIf(NumberOfHours = 1, " ", "s ") & _
    NumberOfMinutes & " Minute" & _
    IIf(NumberOfMinutes = 1, " ", "s ") & _
    NumberOfSeconds & " Second" & _
    IIf(NumberOfsecondss = 1, "", "s")
End Function
```